# How can I create a translucent copy of a QPixmap?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qpixmap

In the program I'm making, I need two images, which are exactly the same but one is translucent. For performance reasons, I want to create two separate `QPixmaps` instead of using just one and setting the opacity of a `QPainter`. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no performant way to do this.

To modify channels of a `QPixmap` it must be: Converted into a `QImage`, modified, converted back to a `QPixmap`. Depending upon your application the round trip will probably make it simpler to just do this in the `QPainter`: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/51158-setting-QPixmap-s-alpha-channel

However if you could do roll this into your startup time the round trip may be reasonable, preventing repeated conversions in `QPainter`.

1. Convert your `QPixmap` to a `QImage`:http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#toImage
2. If you didn't have an alpha channel in your `QPixmap` you'll need to add one: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#convertToFormat
3. Then for each pixel in your image call `setPixel`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#pixel-manipulation (Note that `setPixel` takes a `QRgb`. You'll need to get the red, green, and blue channels from the pixel to be modified and use these along with your desired alpha value in `qRgba`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#qRgba)
4. Finally you'll need to use `convertFromImage`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#convertFromImage

Comment: Yes, the intention was to perform this once at startup so I wouldn't have to do it every time I needed the translucent image. The link you provided is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-painting-imagecomposition-example.html). I think you will need to use [the composition mode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#CompositionMode-enum) for this purpose.